# android: nullpointer when saving images

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to take an image, optimize it as a 65% jpeg and save it to the phones storage.
The code below is working fine for me on my nexus one, but is returning a null pointer exception on the last line.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
// image passed in from camera
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, opts);

// create output
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

// create filename & directory
String nameFile = "ms" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".jpg";
String directory = "/DCIM/MySeats/";

// try creating the directories if they don't already exist         
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),directory);
file.mkdirs();

// prep output
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ directory + nameFile);
optimizedImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ directory + nameFile;

// write file through a buffered stream
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

// This line causes a null pointer exception on some phones?
// What am I missing?
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, bos);
```

Comment: If it is only returning null pointer on some phones, which ones have you tried and which ones finished correctly?

Comment: @User: can you see your Log and tell me , in which line that errors occurs

Comment: Hello! I have the same problem, sometimes it is works sometimes it ins't. The users reported this problem, so I can't check their device. Do you know something about the SDcards? I think we got this, if there is no SD card in the phone ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null pointer exception in the last line is due to the two variable that is used in the last line is null

check for bm != null
check for bos!= null

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are launching the native camera application and this code is all probably from the onActivityResult() method.
Your problem could be that a couple of phones with the carrier specific builds disregard the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter and just return the image in the returned `Intent`. This would mean the image at the path you expect is null and you have to extract the image from the intent using `getData()` sometimes.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm going to have to investigate this further.

Comment: If you find that's what it is you should edit your question to include the relevant code and I'll post a more complete answer that will be useful to people looking for this issue. My current answer is pretty cursory as it is really just based on a hunch and might not be relevant.